# Angular 4.0.0 documentation

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to see the documentation URL for previous releases of angular like Angular 4.0.0 or Angular 4.2.0. Angular.io only has documentation of 4.4.4 which is latest version as of today. I want use little older version of angular to get support for relatively older version of google chrome. I also checked github but could not find old version documentation.

Comment: Angular Change Log to  the rescue - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic, but it addresses a real issue. Sometimes the docs change during the work on one project. This results in strange issues like examples from the docs not working.

Comment: @Henry such a problem can be solved to keep updating to the newest version. As long as there is no breaking changes keep updating , you'll gain new features and bug fixes.

Comment: @marouanekadiri some people, like me, prefer to have a stable working environment and to do version upgrades only when there is a good time for it (e.g. not a few days before a delivery deadline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into [**Angular Change Log**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Angular Document cannot update according to what the current build is that is the reason they have a changelog file which describes all the versions that they are working on presently . As of today **Angular v5 RC 0** is released and the stable is **4.4.4**. You can Find docs for all the beta versions the PR for each breaking change and added concepts.